# Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are 1, 1 and 3

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are 1, 1 and 3.
Express $A^{-1}$ in the form $\alpha I+\beta A$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

***My Idea :***

since eigenvalues are  $1,1,3$ then characteristic equation is $(x-1)^2(x-3)=0$

then $x^3-5x^2+7x-3=0$ since A satisfies the characteristic equation

hence $A^3-5A^2+7A-3I=0\rightarrow 3A^{-1}=A^2-5A+7I$

now minimal equation is $(x-1)(x-3)=0$ and $A$ also satisfies the minimal equation so $A^2=4A-3I$

so $A^{-1}=\frac{4}{3}I-\frac{1}{3}A$

is i am correct...

Comment: is we use minimal equation of the characteristic equation  so A also satsfies the minimal equation so $A^2-4A+3I=0$

Comment: You should write that as your own answer.